# Pass List of Objects in XSLT Argument List and Access it in xsl in C#

Tags: c#, xslt

I 've a class which i use in XSL

```
public class PurchaseOrderDTO
{
    public IList<PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO> PurchaseOrderDetailsDTOList { get; set; }
    public String PONo { get; set; }
    public Decimal POValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PODate { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the xsl i use

```
<P>
  Dear,
</P>
Purchase Order No <xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrderDTO:get_PONo()" /> has
being created <BR />
Purchase Order Value <xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrderDTO:get_POValue()" /> <BR />
<BR />
Purchase Order Date <xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrderDTO:get_PODate()" /> <BR />
<BR />

<xsl:for-each select="PurchaseOrderDTO:get_PurchaseOrderDetailsDTOList()">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>      
        Item name
      </p>
      <xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO:get_Item()"></xsl:value-of>
    </li>
  </ul>
</xsl:for-each>
```

```
  private static PurchaseOrderDTO GetPurchaseOrderDTO()
    {
        PurchaseOrderDTO _PurchaseOrderDTO = new PurchaseOrderDTO();
        Random rand = new Random();

        _PurchaseOrderDTO.PODate = DateTime.Now;
        _PurchaseOrderDTO.PONo = "PO3333";
        _PurchaseOrderDTO.POValue = rand.Next(40200, 960000);

        IList<PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO> _PurchaseOrderDetailsDTOList = new List<PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO _PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO = new PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO();
            _PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO.ID = (Int16)i;
            _PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO.Item = "Item" + i;
            _PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(rand.Next(100, 500) * i);
            _PurchaseOrderDetailsDTOList.Add(_PurchaseOrderDetailsDTO);
        }

        _PurchaseOrderDTO.PurchaseOrderDetailsDTOList = _PurchaseOrderDetailsDTOList;

        return _PurchaseOrderDTO;


    }

    private static void GetEmailTemplate()
    {
        PurchaseOrderDTO _PurchaseOrderDTO = GetPurchaseOrderDTO();

        XslTransform _XslTransform = new XslTransform();
        _XslTransform.Load("../../Transformer.xslt");

        XmlDocument _XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        _XmlDocument.AppendChild(_XmlDocument.CreateElement("Root"));

        XPathNavigator _XPathNavigator = _XmlDocument.CreateNavigator();

        XsltArgumentList _XsltArgumentList = new XsltArgumentList();


        Hashtable _Hashtable = new Hashtable();
        _Hashtable["PurchaseOrderDTO"] = _PurchaseOrderDTO;

        if (_Hashtable != null)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in _Hashtable)
            {
                _XsltArgumentList.AddExtensionObject(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value);
            }
        }

        StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlTextWriter _XmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(_sb));

        _XslTransform.Transform(_XPathNavigator, _XsltArgumentList, _XmlTextWriter);

        Console.WriteLine(_sb.ToString());



    }
```

But in ouput i m not getting child properties values.Is it possible to access list item values in XsltArgumentList?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is, I'm afraid. Playing around with your code I get errors telling me that return types of List'1 aren't supported (i.e. the collection of detail objects)

Checking the [XSLT extension objects documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf741884.aspx) tells me this:

> The data types returned from extension
>   objects are one of the four basic
>   XPath data types of number, string,
>   Boolean, and node set

Which is kind of explicit that arbitrary CLR objects aren't supported in the way that you're trying to use them.

It might be worth approaching the problem slightly differently - it you want to merge CLR objects with a template like this then precompiled T4 templates would probably be a better option. I've got a blog post describing this here: [Using T4 to generate content at runtime](http://www.goatly.net/2010/11/19/using-t4-to-generate-content-at-runtime.aspx)